# Force embed space character?

Tags: luatex

As I recall, circa 2014 using pdfTeX, it was possible to force embedding of a font's space character. Then, the space character would be in the PDF. Later, if FontForge was used to extract the font, it would have the space character.

This behavior seems to have disappeared in the intervening time, or I can no longer figure out how to do it. I am actually more interested in LuaLaTeX than pdfTeX nowadays.

I do not intend to place the space character at each point in the document where space appears. It only needs to be included once, for each font used.

Why I ask: Back in 2014, I noticed that a PDF reader could more reliably extract text from the PDF, if the space character was embedded. My guess is that without the space character, the reader calculates where space should be, based on a comparison of gaps to the space-width of some default font (Times Roman?). But if it knows the actual advance width of the font's space, it more accurately extracts words, espacially when the tracking is close.

Note that I do not want an "explicit space" (like U) printed.

Comment: With pdftex you can use ` \pdfinterwordspaceon` see the documenation. With luatex it won't work. I asked about it last november on the context list and Hans Hagen wrote that one should use a callback if one wants to insert space character but didn't give concrete code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The \dfinterwordspace inserts a dummy space, not the actual space from the main font. Maybe good for PDF/A, but not my purpose (also, as you noted, not in luatex). But I have since discovered a simple solution: Temporarily change the catcode of the space from 10 to 12, insert space, change catcode back to 10. Works! Again, I am only trying to insert the space once.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't read your question very carefully. If you only want to insert a space char you can use `X\char"20 X`.  This gives in my test `007300670073`, (the 0067 is mapped to `<0020>` later on). A simple space `X X` gives a space instruction `-333`. (all tests done with luatex).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes indeed that works. Please put as answer so I can accept it. Much better than my own hack with catcode (because incorrect use of catcode can cause problems).

Comment: Tomorrow ... Have to go now

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I remember hearing something about space character in TUG2020 in Ross Moore's presentation on accessibility (though I don't remember exactly what he said). I also read the Hans conversation you mention here from Nov 2016. Actually he does seem to suggest a solution: `replace all skips with char 32 right before shipout` (so I guess a latelua function), though I am no expert to know if that would work. I wonder what is the future of space character. I tried running a sample luatex generated pdf through Google's new  Vision API today, and there is no space between so many words.

Comment: @reportaman the tagpdf package contains code to add the space chars. It works quite ok, but the code is currently intertwined with the tagging code and so can not be used standalone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to insert a space *char* you can use with luatex the `\char` or `\symbol` command with (hex) `"20` or (dezimal) 32 `X\char"20 X`.

Be aware that this chars don't stretch or shrink. If this is needed I suggest to use `\rlap` and an additional normal space.

For the following document -- if compiled with luatex -- the uncompress pdf then contains

```
 <00730067007300670073>-29334<0073>
```

and

```
 <00730067>-9670<00730067>-9670<0073>-9994<0073>
```

where the `0067` is the space char and the `-29334` is from the normal space (here stretched a lot).

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

X\symbol{32}X\char32X X\linebreak
YYY

X\rlap{\symbol{32}} X\rlap{\char32} X X\linebreak
YYY

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the helpful information which I accepted above, I have looked at this in greater detail. I believe I have found a solution which (a) embeds the actual font space character everywhere a space appears in the text (not just once), so that Adobe Reader reflows it correctly, (b) allows proper hyphenation, and (c) allows microtype protrusion, at least at the right margin, where it is more important.

This is a LuaLaTeX-only solution, with fontspec. Also, it is a "text-only" solution, meaning that I have not tested it in math mode (and do not intend to do that, knowing no math).

FIRST, the document body text must be pre-processed. This is easily done in a text editor via search and replace (with \n as regular expression for newline) and can be automated by a sed script, for those with the knowledge.

(A) No multiple space characters.

(B) No space character followed by newline.

(C) No newline followed by space character.

(D) If you have any macro definitions within the document body (not just calls to macros), then move them to the top of the body. The following commands must go after any other macro definitions. Reason: You probably don't want any ordinary spaces to be converted to real spaces, within a macro definition!

(E) In some cases, an ordinary space following a macro will not be gobbled, because it will become a real space. So, manually edit by replacing those ordinary spaces with {}. Thus:

```
\noindent{}This is not indented.\par
{\centering{}This is centered.\par}
\noindent{}Left\hfill{}Right\par
```

So far, there should be no real change to the document. Unless you were using verbatim text, it should compile just the same as it did before.

SECOND, After \begin{document} (not in Preamble), place the following code. Macro "\ibs" stands for "itty bitty space" and may be re-named if you have a name conflict. The plusminus character was chosen as something that I do not use anywhere in my documents, but it can be any Unicode character (feel free to pick a Cherokee or Hiragana character instead, as long as you can paste it from a character map and see it in your text editor, for the text editor's font).

```
\def\ibs{{\addfontfeature{Scale=.001}\char"20}}
\catcode`\±=10\relax
\catcode`\ =13\relax
\def {±\ibs}
```

THIRD, just before \end{document} write this:

```
\catcode`\ =10\relax
```

I am not sure if the above is always necessary, but it certainly does not hurt.

Result: It takes a very, very long time to compile. But it compiles, with satisfactory PDF. For each font actually used (regular, italic, whatever) the space character will be present in the PDF, wherever used. In Adobe Reader, requesting View > Reflow will properly reflow the PDF, with word spacing.

I imagined that the PDF would be about 20 percent larger than without the spaces, but it is actually much larger. Perhaps I could tweak compression, but I have not looked at that yet.

Note: Anything involving a box (such as \rlap) may break hyphenation there.

EDIT: Upon further investigation, I have discovered that Adobe Reader uses some heuristic algorithm for reflow, when the items are in a table or centered layout, or otherwise have some kind of horizontal position. The algorithm is not obvious. For example, a succession of independently centered lines will be reflowed as separate lines if they begin with a numeral, but concatenated if they do not begin with a numeral (and, roman numbers are not considered to be numerals). However, the "add tags" capability of Adobe Acrobat Pro does a much better job, apparently based only on position.